# How to upload apple developer certificate into shopify website?

Tags: shopify

I had add the stripe in my shop, it works fine. I want add apple pay to my shop also. I visited document in the stripe website. it's said  I must upload a verification file to the server of my domain, I cunfused it. what should I do

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to log into the admin area of the store. From there go to settings, all the way at the bottom on the left side.

[image]

Then go to files; it's the third from the bottom.

[image]

You can upload the certificate there.

[image]

Comment: I'm tried to complete the domain verification step. but it shown as Verification failed for domain Unable to establish a secure connection to 'https://my.domain/.well-known/apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association'.

Comment: I have no information as to what you have done so far and what you have not done. Have you [followed these steps](https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/payments/accelerated-checkouts/apple-pay)?

Comment: yes i followed this steps..